# Concatenar variables para usar un JQuery genérico en varios textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy teniendo un problema, necesito que pase lo siguiente:
Que el usuario cuando clique en un textarea le aparezca el contador de caracteres, en este caso, 0/250. Hasta ahí todo ok.
El problema lo estoy teniendo cuando intento poner el mismo javascript para todos los textareas, es decir, quiero utilizar un javascript genérico para todos los textareas, concatenando los id. Os muestro:

Por un lado el script:

```html
<script>
  function contarcaracteres (){
    var total=250;
 
    setTimeout(function(){
      var valor=document.getElementById('fe563');
      var respuesta=document.getElementById('res');
      var cantidad=valor.value.length;
 
      if(document.getElementById('lang').value == 'ES') {
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = cantidad + ' de 250 (quedan ' + (total - cantidad) + ')';}
      else{
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = cantidad + ' de 250 (queden ' + (total - cantidad) + ')';}
 
 
    });
 
 
 
  }
</script>
```

Y por otro lado el textarea y el div:

```html
<textarea class="algo-mas" id="fe563" maxlength="250" name="P5" onpaste="contarcaracteres();" onkeyup="contarcaracteres();"></textarea>
<div id="res" style="margin: 0px 200px 0px 10px; color: #BFBABA" >0</div>
```

Ahora bien, necesito que el mismo script sin duplicarlo o triplicarlo sirva para los siguientes textareas:

```html
<textarea class="algo-mas" name="PCC1" id="fe589"></textarea>
<div id="res" style="margin: 0px 200px 0px 10px; color: #BFBABA" >0</div>
 
<textarea class="algo-mas" name="PCC2" id="fe590"></textarea>
<div id="res" style="margin: 0px 200px 0px 10px; color: #BFBABA" >0</div>
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Uno de los primeros problemas que veo en tu código es que tus elementos de tipo `<div>` tienen el mismo [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id). Por lo tanto debes cambiar eso. Por otro lado, lo que tú deseas hacer es añadir un [`listener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) al evento [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) de tu `<textarea>`. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He reescrito tu función, tenías varias cosas que me chocaban, como elementos con la misma **ID** o el uso de la función `setTimeout()` (que no entiendo muy bien para que se estaba usando). Una vez arreglados esos fallos mi solución parte del uso e la función `each()` de **JQuery**. Con ella podemos capturar una colección de elementos para poder ir iterándola una a una, de esa manera no nos hace falta diferenciar cada `<text-area>` por **ID**.

Por otr lado, la función `keyup` es la más adecuada para conseguir que segun vayas escribiendo las cantidades se vayan actualizando.

```js
//Función que se ejecuta al cargar el DOM
$(function () {
  //Llamamos a la función al cargar el DOM para que las cantidades aparezcan
  contarcaracteres();
  
  //Vinculamos un evento keyup a todos los textareas
  $(document).on('keyup', 'textarea', contarcaracteres);
});


function contarcaracteres () {
    let total = 250;
    //Capturamos todos los textareas
    let textos = $('textarea');
    //Inicializamos cantidad a cero, para la primera carga
    let cantidad = 0;
    
    //Recorremos cada textarea
    textos.each(function() {
      //Capturamos el número de caracteres del textarea que se está iterando
      let cantidad = $(this).val().length;
      //Capturamos el elemento hermano consecutivo del textarea que se está iterando
      //en nuestro caso el div .res emparejado con él.
      let respuesta = $(this).next();
      
      if($('#lang').val() == 'ES') {
       respuesta.html(cantidad + ' de 250 (quedan ' + (total - cantidad) + ')');
      }
      else {
        respuesta.html(cantidad + ' de 250 (queden ' + (total - cantidad) + ')');
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="lang" value="ES">

<textarea class="algo-mas" name="PCC1" id="fe589"></textarea>
<div class="res" style="margin: 0px 200px 0px 10px; color: #BFBABA" >0</div>
 
<textarea class="algo-mas" name="PCC2" id="fe590"></textarea>
<div class="res" style="margin: 0px 200px 0px 10px; color: #BFBABA" >0</div>
```

El `this` dentro de la función `each()` hace referencia al elemento que se está iterando, que en cada vuelta del bucle será uno de los `<textarea>` que se encuentre en el **DOM**.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando JQuery (que aparentemente, no lo estás utilizando) puedes ponerle a todos los textarea la misma clase (como la que ya tienes "algo-mas") y asociarle un evento a esa clase y así mostrar el div de debajo.

```
$('.algo-mas').on("paste keyup", function(){...}):
```

Tienes más información de la función "on" aquí: https://api.jquery.com/on/
En los puntos suspensivos tienes que indicar en que div quieres escribir el contador.
Sino sabes como vincular los textarea con los div correspondiente, puedes hacerlo mediante atributos data.